# How to count certain texts coming from VLOOKUP function?

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

[image: Type and Step Counts]

I want to count a certain type with a certain step. 
For instance, I want to count Type A and Step 1 with    `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"A",B:B,"Step 1")`.
However, Steps from Column B come from VLOOKUP function that fetches from different Excel file: for instance, `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AC9,'Sheet X'!$B$1:$Y$893,21,FALSE),"")`. Is there a way to count a certain text that comes from `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: COUNTIFS will still work if the column B contains a vlookup. If if doesn't, there's a mismatch between your criterion ("Step 1") in the COUNTIFS and the actual data in column B (check for leading/trailing spaces, typos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the double unary operator for counting instances like this, it allows you to easily combine as many conditions like this as you like:

```
=sumproduct(--($A$1:$A$893 = "A", $B$1:$B$893 = "Step 1"))
```

You can add more conditions by addint commas within the --() section of the sumproduct.  What this does is force each column to a one/zero array of the condition (1 if = "A") and multiplies them together, so only if all conditions are true / 1, they'll be counted.  In this instance the function will return the value 2, as both are true only for two rows.

If the values in the steps column come from a vlookup, it would not affect this function, as it is just using the values in the cell shown.